# ConstructUsingServiceLocator in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I found a method in AutoMapper: `IMappingExpression.ConstructUsingServiceLocator()`.

When should I use this method and what are the differences between it and `ConstructUsing`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used to configure AutoMapper to use certain constructor to instantiate a class.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        // Adding "Construct" configuration 
        cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(t => new Dest(5));

        // Tell AutoMapper to use already defined configuration to construct Dest class
        cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
           .ConstructUsingServiceLocator();
    });
```

The best way to learn AutoMapper is to look into the [unit tests](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/tree/master/src/UnitTests).